# Perl split and regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, split

I have the following string:

```
'100% California Grown Olives, Water, Salt And Ferrous Gluconate (An,Iron, Derivative),asasd, sadasda'
```

I'm trying to split it by `/,/` but **only if**  its not inside brackets, for instance, in this case the result should be:

```
100% California Grown Olives
Water
Salt And Ferrous Gluconate (An,Iron, Derivative)
asasd
sadasda
```

thanks,

Comment: Is there a possibility of nested parentheses?  If so, regexes might not fit the bill.

Comment: nope, not possible. only single pair of parentheses, or couple but NOT nested

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@result = split(m/,(?![^()]*\))/, $subject);
```

This splits on a comma only if the next following parenthesis (if any) isn't a closing parenthesis. As Jack Maney noted correctly, this can lead to failure if nested parentheses may occur.

**Explanation:**

```
,       # Match a comma.
(?!     # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 [^()]* # any number of non-parenthesis characters
 \)     # followed by a closing parenthesis
)       # End of lookahead assertion
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what constitutes parens, and if they can be nested. (for this answer, I will assume that they can be).  Then you need to remove those paren blocks from the text and replace it with a placeholder:

```
my @parens;
$str =~ s/( \( (?: (?0)|[^()] )* \) )/push @parens, $1; "PARENS_$#parens"/gex;
```

So now you are left with something that looks like:

```
'100% California Grown Olives, Water, Salt And Ferrous Gluconate PAREN_0,asasd,
sadasdas.'
```

And it is simple now to split it on commas.  Then on each of the split pieces, scan for `PAREN_\d+` tokens, and replace them with the ones from the `@parens` array.  You might need to use a more unique placeholder name depending on your source content.

Something like:

```
s/PARENS_(\d+)/$parens[$1]/ge for my @segs = split /,\s*/ => $str;

say for @segs;
```

which for an example string:

```
my $str = "foo (b,a,r), baz (foo, (bar), baz), biz";
```

prints:

```
foo (b,a,r)
baz (foo, (bar), baz)
biz
```

Comment: I don't think you need to evaluate `$parens[$1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to build a regexp for what you want to match, rather than what you want to remove. (This assumes that you don't want to limit the number of matches.)